# Cannot find constructor in java class via jni

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-source

i am developing a service on system app level for a custom rom which i'm currently building. The Service does some JNI calls and my c++ code should return an object of a custom result class.
When it runs as a normal app on a normal device, e.g. nexus 7, everything is ok and no problem at all.

But now comes the strange part: When i put the service in my rom directory and compile everything it does find the class of my result object, but it does not find the constructor via GetMethodID or any other method of that class.

Here are some snippets of my code:

1. The method which is called to return a result object to my java code.

   ```
   static jobject wrapResult(jint rc, jint errCode,
               jstring errString) {
       JNIEnv *env = GetJniEnv();
       jclass lresultClass = env->FindClass(
                   "pathtoclass/Result");
       if (!lresultClass)
           LOGW(TAG, "!resultclass");

          jmethodID constructor = GetJniEnv()->GetMethodID(lresultClass, "<init>",
                   "(IILjava/lang/String;)V"); 
          if (!constructor)
               LOGW(TAG, "!constructor");
      jobject obj = env->NewObject(resultClass, constructor, rc, errCode,
      errString);
      return obj;


   }

   JNIEnv* GetJniEnv() {
       JNIEnv* pEnv = NULL;
       pJVM->GetEnv((void**) &pEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_4);
       pJVM->AttachCurrentThread(&pEnv, NULL);
       return pEnv;
   }
   ```

And the constructor in my java result class:

```
public Result(int result, int errType, String errMsg) {
    this.result = result;
    this.errType = errType;
    this.errMsg = errMsg;
}
```

I'm building for galaxy nexus maguro and the code fails when it tries to get the methodID of the constructor. I have no idea why it finds the class but no methods.

Comment: what does javap -s give ?

Comment: public path.Result(int, int, java.lang.String);
  Signature: (IILjava/lang/String;)V 

Exactly the signature i'm using.

Comment: i think calling getJniEnv twice may be a problem, as you attach the thread each time. try using the env variable to call getMethodID

Comment: @njzk2, AttachCurrentThread is essentialy a no-op if the thread is already attached ([here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/vLt3ncT3I4g) or [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1550947)). Cattivo, are you sure that you are building the same, fully valid native lib exporting all symbols, when you are compiling for the rom target? Can you get the lib back out of the rom and have a look at the exported symbols?

Comment: but does GetEnv returns the same pointer each time ?

Comment: @PavelZdenek I guess i was building the same as my build for the emulator worked correctly. i don't have the time to look deeper in the built libs and so on but i found a messy solution for the start. i just precompiled it with the android ndk and made build a apk which i added as a prebuilt to my system. i compiled the whole thing for maguro and it works. not a good solution but for now it works. I will go deeper when i have time to do so. @ njzk2 GetEnv returned the same pointer. Despite my messy solution, thanks to both of you.